# dealing with Date and Time separately

Tags: android, date, time, android-calendar, android-date

I want to deal with date and time separately in my android app, by saying separately I mean setting the time without affecting the date and vice versa, So, when setting the time only:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR + 1990, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, hours, minutes, 0);
```

and it works perfectly, but when setting the Date only:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(new_date);
```

I face a problem of having the time set to **00:00:00**, So, I tried to save the time values before and set the date the following way:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(new_date);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR + 1990, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, saved_hours, saved_minutes, 0);
```

But that makes the date saved as it's default value as (`Calendar.YEAR`||`.MONTH`||`.DAY_OF_MONTH`) returns the **zero** date values of the device which is a date in 1990's despite I'm excuting this command after setting the new Date.

**Hint**: Methods (`mDate.getYear()`, `mDate.getMonth`, .....etc) are deprecated.

Comment: There are pitfalls to not setting date prior to the time. For instance locale with daylight savings time translate to different GMT times depending on the date set.

Comment: @mach I can't understand your point

Comment: try this code  calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 4);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 40);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Comment: @minafawzy my problem is in the Date not the time

Comment: Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, YorDay);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, YourMonth - 1);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, Youryear);

Comment: notice month -1 , it start from zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set date and time separately you can use this code

```
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Note: Months value is MonthNumber-1 (Jan is 0, Feb is 1 and so on).
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 9);
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 24);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2013);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR,1);         // when wanting to set it as 12 Hour system
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,13); // when wanting to set it as 24 Hour system
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,45);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,52);

  // set the year,month and day to something else
  //set(int year,int month,int day)
  cal.set(1995, 5, 25);


// set(int year,int month,int day,int hourOfDay, int minute,int second)
   cal.set(1995, 5, 25, 04, 15, 20);
```